# reinterpret_cast strangeness ( comma separated expression )

Tags: c++

While debugging some of our code (C++) I found this:

```
inline std::string BufferToStr(
    const unsigned char* buffer,
    int index,
    size_t length)
{
   std::string retValue(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[index], length));
   return retValue;
}
```

The issue with this code (overlooking the lack of pointer and string length checks) is that the closing parenthesis of the `reinterpret_cast` has been placed after `length` when it should have been after `&buffer[index]`. At first I thought that this was an issue with the compiler (using VS2013) but after successfully compiling it using both VS2012 and gcc 4.6.3, I've come to the conclusion that this is for some reason allowed. The code won't run on either Windows or Linux as the length parameter is used as the pointer.

So my question is why does this compile? Looking at the documentation of `reinterpret_cast` I can't find any documentation on it saying that you can pass a comma separated list of values to it and what it will do with it.

Comment: Why should it not compile? You're telling the compiler to cast a `size_t` to a `const char*`, and it does that. It doesn't need to make sense to be allowed.

Comment: Note that enabling warning would have given a strong indication of what was going on as I showed in my answer with an example using `gcc`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` accepts an [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). What you have in the parenthesis is an expression - the ["," operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) with two sub-expressions, which will evaluate to the result of last sub-expression.

Comment: Comma operator was the answer. I had forgotten about that one. A quick look at section 5.18 in Stroustrup's old "The Annotated C++ Reference Manual" explained it quite well. Thank you for your quick answer.

Answer (score 7):

That is due to the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in c/c++. The code(an expression):

```
(&buffer[index], length)
```

is equivalent to (&buffer[index] take no effect):

`(length)`

so your code is equivalent to:

```
inline std::string BufferToStr(const unsigned char* buffer, int index, size_t length)
{
   std::string retValue(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(length));
   return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). It evaluates the expressions on both sides of the comma, but return the result of the right-hand expression.

The reason the compiler doesn't complain is because you simple tell the compiler that the result of the expression (of type `size_t`) should be treated as it was a `const char*` expression. That's what `reinterpret_cast` does, it allows the casting of almost any type to almost any other type, no matter how stupid it may be.

Answer (score 3):

```
reinterpret_cast < new_type > ( expression )
```

`reinterpret_cast` accept an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/625x66bt.aspx). Here you have a comma operator who evaluates the expressions on both sides and returns the righ-hand expression.

In fact, the expression `(&buffer[index], length)` is equivalent to `(length)` here.

Just see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator for comma operator explanations.

**To conclude, here you are telling your compiler to cast a `size_t`(result of the expression) to a `const char*` and it can do that.**

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons why it is important to have warnings enabled, it probably would have helped you solve this on your own. Using `gcc` and running with `-Wall`, this is the warning I received:

```
 warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 std::string retValue(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[index], length));
                                                                  ^
```

You can see the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d837e30e482a46392055054c2d119810-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

The warning tells us that we are using the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_othe) at first this may be a bit puzzling but `reinterpret_cast` is not a function call in which this would not work without using parenthesis as we can see [in this contrived example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1b9ad6f6542b9972a42007480d6f89bf-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51), but an *expression* and in section `5.2` *Postfix expressions* of the draft C++ standard the grammer for *postfix-expression* contains:

```
postfix-expression:
   ...
   reinterpret_cast < type-id > ( expression )
   ...
```

and we can use an `expression` in the argument so `comma operator` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I totally agree with you on this and I usually have the warning level at -Wall. In this project it was set on level 3 in Visual Studio and that didn't generate any warning, I changed it to -Wall but it still didn't warn about this. So it seems like gcc, at least in this case,  is better at reporting warnings.

Comment: @william I used a `gcc` example since you had mentioned you tried `gcc 4.6.3` as well and `gcc` back to at least `4.4.4` also warns, `clang` gives a good warning as well.